# I have a problem while selection

Tags: materials, selection-tools

I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://youtu.be/CRSm-dNOogE

Slight problem however... It only selects one ico sphere at a time and applies the material to that one mesh. When I try to deselect it only get rid of the highlight. It still remains in the properties. I am clearly doing something wrong. Here's a screenshot that partially explains it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qByhd.jpg

( I'm at 4:45 ish in the video)

Comment: Hey :). What part of the video? Please add some description of what you're trying to achieve. And a timestamp. Nobody wants to search in a 10 minute video :). Thanks.

Comment: Somehow, your applied arrays have been separated into individual objects.. to get back in sync with the tutorial, select all the objects, and Ctrl J join them back into one object.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to apply one material to bunch of objects?
1) Apply material to one object.
2) Select all the spheres.
3) Right click on the sphere that has material applied to it to make it active object (it will have yellow contour instead of orange).
4) Do ctrl + L and chose "Material" to link materials.
5) Voila, all spheres have that material.

Comment: that seemed to work... I don't know. It's not letting me asign a material now. I'm terrible at this... oh well

Comment: Don't feel bad @Aeria, everybody gets lost in Blender sometimes :). Chocolate usually helps :).

Comment: Hmmmm.... Not letting assign material... weird. You can try: 1)Select object, go to material tab 2) Click little minus until there are no materials in the window. 3) Hit New and create material for it or if you already have material just use dropdown menu. It should apply material to this object.